# How to save Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

So the thing is that I have a **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** object created in code and I want to save it. However, I want the user to be able to choose the location where the file would be saved.

I tried with Response but didn't really succeeded.

*PS: I'm using ASP.NET Webforms and .NET 4.5 if matters.*

Comment: Can you show us the code at the point you want to save it?  Include your interop objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only choice you have with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` is to save the Excel file to your server then transmit the file to the client.

If that's not what you want, you can use `NPOI`. You can get it as a `NuGet Package`. [NPOI CodePlex](https://npoi.codeplex.com/)

With `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`:

```
string filname = @"C:\Upload\filename.xls";
workBook.SaveAs(filname)
workBook.Close();

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"; //xls
// For xlsx, use: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
Response.AddHeader(String.Format("content-disposition", "attachment; filename={0}"), Path.GetFileName(filename));
Response.TransmitFile(filname);
Response.End();
```

With `NPOI`:

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = (HSSFSheet)workbook.CreateSheet("SheetName");

using (MemoryStream exportData = new MemoryStream())
{
    workbook.Write(exportData);
    Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    Response.Charset = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").EncodingName;
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"; //xls
    // For xlsx, use: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}.xls", "yourFilename"));
    Response.Clear();
    Response.BinaryWrite(exportData.GetBuffer());
    Response.End();
}
```